# How to make a Python script runs as trivial linux command with Distutils?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, command

I need to run python module as trivial Linux command without worrying about the location of the file. Can I do it with Distutils?

Specific about what I need. A user should do simple installation and be able to use it:

```
python setup.py install
mymodule --arg value
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a list of scripts in `setup()`, distutils will automatically install them into an appropriate directory:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='somemodule',
    scripts=['mymodule']
)
```

Note that `mymodule` here for your example will need to be a runnable python script with that name; it probably shouldn't be your actual module but rather import your module if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to run the command by specifying just it's name, it needs to be installed in a directory listed in the `PATH` environment variable. For user programs, the usual locations are `/bin`, `/usr/bin` (with `/usr/local/bin` being fairly common too).

So setup your package to install your script in one those locations. However, this will require `root` privileges.

If you want to be able to install without `root` privileges, the alternative is to ensure that the script's directory is listed in the `PATH` variable.

Comment: How to add script path to `PATH` from setup.py?

Comment: If you want to install with `root` privileges, you can do it the way Wooble suggested (setup.py will default to a standard system directory which is mostly likely in `PATH` already).